# glib: sort by multiple attributes

Tags: sorting, glib

I am using glib to sort:

```
gint cmp_values_by_attr1(gpointer a, gpointer b) {
   my_strcut *seq_a = *((my_strcut**) a);
   my_strcut *seq_b = *((my_strcut**) b);
   return (seq_a->attr1 - seq_b->attr1);
}
values = g_ptr_array_sized_new(4);
v = new_struct();
g_ptr_array_add(values, v);
...
g_ptr_array_sort(values, (GCompFunction) cmp_values_by_attr1);
```

Now inside my array, I would like to sort first by `attr1` and then by `attr2`. How to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used some 'hack' to implement this sorting.

- Make the two attributes to sort to be `uint32_t` types.
- Add another attribute `uint64_t` `for_sort` to my struct
- Shift the upper 32 bits of `for_sort` to be `attr1`
- The lower 32 bits of `for_sort` to be `attr2`
- Sort the array by `for_sort`, then the items are first sorted by `attr1`, then by `attr2`.

I have implemented and verified that it is working.

Disadvantages:

- Extra memory to add `for_sort`
- Extra processing
- If the sorting attributes are in other types, need to change accordingly.

Comment: That would be valid for unsigned integers, but not signed ones.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple—the comparison function returns less than, equal to, or greater than zero depending on whether the first value is less than, equal to, or greater than the second value.  All you need to do is compare the first attributes and if the return value is not equal to zero return the result, otherwise compare the second attributes and return the result:

```
gint comp_values (gpointer a, gpointer b) {
  gint res;
  my_strcut *seq_a = *((my_strcut**) a);
  my_strcut *seq_b = *((my_strcut**) b);

  res = seq_a->attr1 - seq_b->attr1;
  if (res == 0) {
    res = (seq_a->attr2 - seq_b->attr2);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In it's current state your answer might not be of much use to other people looking for answer to this question.